# Creating HTML Forms with Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first attempt at building a single page web app.  I am working on the layout of the page first.  I have 99% of the CSS done (using bootstrap).  However, I now need to add a form to my page.  The form will kick off scripts on the server.

I would like the form to have Tabs that the user can click on and each tab will obviously contain different input fields (text boxes, drop down lists, check boxes etc...).  However, I am not seeing any good tutorials on how to accomplish this purely with HTML/CSS or even js.

I don't want to re-invent the wheel here, but I want a form that is responsive and can be updated dynamically without reloading the page.  I would prefer pure HTML/CSS but if js is needed then that works as well.

I'm not exactly sure if I should create this HTML form from scratch myself, or use a framework or template.

Comment: Couple of things, firstly you question doesn't contain a question mark. you really need a definitive question so people know what they are answering :)

Comment: secondly - you're already using a framework that can do what you are asking neat forms and tabs, it's just a case of marrying up the two - take a look here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs at how tabs work.

Comment: Kara has a point, in10s1. Although, stating a need for knowledge and explaining your lack of related knowledge is is valid, those who scan for the question mark and don't read whole questions for efficiency's sake can get confused.

Answer (score 1):

Most times I see tabs created, they aren't "real" tabs. Just make however many divs that are equal to the number of tabs, position them in the same spot, and have each tab you click activate java-script to set its respective linked div as visible and the others to hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Bootstrap + Jquery, I would recommend that you use [Toggleable Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) component of bootstrap.

Also, for this specific case of creating forms with tabs, this post could prove to be useful: http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-tab/